# Computing kernel

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I,J$ be two ideals of Noetherian ring $R$. How to compute kernel of following homomorphism directly:
$$\phi: R/I\oplus R/J\to R/(I+J) $$ 
$$(a+I,b+J)\to (a-b)+I+J $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: the sequence

$$0 \to R/(I \cap J) \xrightarrow{\Delta} R/I \oplus R/J \xrightarrow{\phi} R/(I+J) \to 0$$

where $\Delta(a + (I \cap J)) = (a + I, a + J)$, is exact.

**Edit:** To see exactness, let $(a+I,b+J) \in \ker \phi$. Then $a - b \in I + J$, so $a - b = i + j$ for some $i \in I, j \in J$. Then $a - i = b + j$, so $\Delta((a-i)+(I \cap J)) = ((a-i)+I, (b+j)+J) = (a+I,b+J)$.

Comment: I know this SES but I wanna compute kernel of $\phi$ directly(by definition).

Comment: Are you trying to show that the sequence is exact?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: It's not hard to check that this is exact. Was that worth a downvote?

Comment: Apparently we have posted the proof simultaneously. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

The homomorphism
$$i : R/(I \cap J) \to R/I \times R/J, ~ a+(I \cap J) \mapsto (a+I,a+J)$$
is clearly injective and factors through the kernel of $\phi$. Conversely, let $(a+I,b+J)$ be in the kernel of $\phi$, i.e. $a+I+J=b+I+J$. Choose $i \in I$, $j \in J$ such that $a=b+i+j$, or $c:=a-i=b+j$. Then $(a+I,b+J)=(c+I,c+J)$ lies in the image of $i$.

This shows that $i$ is a kernel of $\phi$.

By the way, this also says that we have an isomorphism of $R$-algebras
$$R/(I \cap J) \cong R/I \times_{R/(I+J)} R/J.$$
For $I+J=R$ we recover the Chinese Remainder Theorem.